Having trouble with adding subtitle to video using FFMPEG Wasm react
Here is the part of the code:
const srtBlob = new Blob([srtContent], { type: "text/srt" });
const srtArrayBuffer = await srtBlob.arrayBuffer();

// Load files into FFmpeg
await ffmpeg.writeFile("input.mp4", new Uint8Array(videoArrayBuffer));
await ffmpeg.writeFile("subtitles.srt", new Uint8Array(srtArrayBuffer));

// Run FFmpeg command to hardwire subtitles to video

await ffmpeg.exec(["-i", "subtitles.srt", "subtitles.ass"]);

await ffmpeg.exec([
  "-i",
  "input.mp4",
  "-vf",
  "ass=subtitles.ass",
  "-c:v",
  "libx264", // Ensures video encoding
  "-c:a",
  "aac",
  // '-v', 'debug',
  "output.mp4",
]);

I'm getting the output video without subtitle. I checked log of FFMPEG process and found this error : can't find selected font provider.
I tried specifying font in the command, but issue persists.

See: https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues/588
